# Using UnityEngine in Monodevelop (Arch linux)

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, archlinux

i just installed Unity3D and everything works fine, except that Monodevelop can't find UnityEngine. I know it's not a big deal because the code isn't compiled there but it does't have code complition and it's just annoying because it seems like such a little thing.

I have the UnityEngine.dll and i have tried adding it to the project directory, nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added it as a Project Reference?

Comment: I'm not sure i know what you mean. If this is something that i do in Monodevelop i can't, because it opens a file, not a project, so the project settings are disabled.                                                             **Edit:** My first idea was to copy the dll where the default libraries, that monodevelop uses, are. I can't find them though.